# Platform for benchmarking of classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, benchmarking, text-classification

I need a platform (java) using for testing of different text classifiers by single training/benchmarking data. Of cause, different classifiers may come from different vendors and have different APIs. Obviously, I will have to write adapters. The propose of the platform is to manage training data and invocation of training/classification/benchmarking. Are you familiar with such open source?

Comment: I would use Knime. It is a quite nice workflow tool. It has a library for text handling which might provide a starting point for extension